# How many independent thermodynamic response functions are there in a system characterized by $T, S, P$, and $V$?

Tags: thermodynamics

In classical thermodynamics, say you have a system characterised by  $T, S, P$, and $V$.
I wonder how many *independent* response function this system has.
There are $\frac{4\cdot3\cdot2}{2}=12$ different ways of choosing three of the four variables, where one of the chosen three is held fixed:
\begin{align}
\text{fixed }P\qquad \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P},\quad \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_{P},\quad \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{P}\\
\text{fixed }V\qquad \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V},\quad \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_{V},\quad \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V}\\
\text{fixed }T\qquad \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T},\quad \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_{T},\quad \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_{T}\\
\text{fixed }S\qquad \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{S},\quad \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_{S},\quad \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{S}
\end{align}
We recognise the heat capacity at fixed volume and pressure, isothermal and adiabatic compressibility, and thermal expansion coefficient:
\begin{align}
C_V&=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V},\quad& C_P&=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{P}\\
\kappa_T&=-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T}, \quad& \kappa_S&=-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T}, \quad&
\beta=-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}
\end{align}

Not all 12 partial derivatives are independent, as we have four Maxwell relations
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S}&=-\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_{V}\\
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_{S}&=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_{p}\\
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{T}&=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V}\\
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_{T}&=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P}
\end{align}
and four cyclic relations (triple product rule)
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_{T}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V}&=-1\\
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{P}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V}&=-1\\
\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_{S}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_{P}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_{V}&=-1\\
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_{S}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_{T}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{P}&=-1
\end{align}
From the above, I would expect there to be $12-4-4=4$ independent response functions.

What confuses me is that $C_V, C_P, \kappa_T, \kappa_S$, and $\beta$ also satisfy the famous relations
\begin{align}
C_P-C_V&=\frac{TV\beta^2}{\kappa_T}\\
\frac{C_P}{C_V}&=\frac{\kappa_T}{\kappa_S},
\end{align}
which, as far as I understand, can be derived using the Maxwell and cyclic relations and *no additional assumptions or constraints*.
But having the five  response functions $C_V, C_P, \kappa_T, \kappa_S$ constraint by two relations would yield three, not four independent response functions.
What am I missing here?

Comment: For a single-phase pure component, specification of any two intensive, independent properties is sufficient to fix all the rest. If $S$ and $V$ are replaced with their specific (per unit mass) values $s$ and $v$, then any two of the four are sufficient to fix the others.